# Refresh changes and new posts in wp query using ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to make a page on wordpress, where all new posts and changes on existing posts will appaer automatically in the feed. The feed will reload every 5 second.

In the code below i only got the records from the database, and every 5 second all the posts will be added again on the end.

How can I check if the post is new or changed after last "get" from the database?

**display.php**

```
<?php include( '../../../../wp-load.php' ); // loads WordPress Environment ?>
<?php
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT ID, post_title 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'post' "
);

foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
{
    echo $fivesdraft->post_title;
}

?>
```

**single.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(ajaxCall, 5000);

function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/wp-bootstrap-starter/inc/display.php',
            success: function(data) {

                $('p').append(data);
            }
        });
}

</script>

        <section id="primary" class="content-area col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
            <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

                <p></p>

            </main><!-- #main -->
        </section><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: So you only want to show posts that have been updated within the last 5 seconds? For example, if only one post has been updated in that interval, only that post is shown? Or do you want to show the most recently updated posts, regardless if they have been updated in the last 5 seconds?

Comment: No, I want to show all the posts, but when a content has been edited, it will change automatic without reload the page. New posts will also show up. But I find a solution - se below.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval("my_function();",3000); // Reload every 3 sec.
function my_function(){
    $('#package_list').load(location.href + ' #package_list'); // Reload content in #package_list div
}
</script>
```

The div with the wordpress query is inside the `<div id="package_list"></div>` and get alle the changes automatic.